# Remove image tag from HTML string using image url

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/u1mt0tbz/ is the code I have so far.  I would like to get the image but also the tag and any attributes and remove them.

```
var image = 'http://www.google.com/logo.gif';
var text = 'alkjsdfkljasd flaksjdflkjasdf klsdjfl skjdflkasjdfl ksjlafj lsdjkflasd jkflasjkdf alsjdf alskdjfal skdfjlaskdjflas kjdflaksdjf laksjdfalskdjf alsdkjflasdjf la <img src="http://www.google.com/logo.gif" /> aljsdfkljaskljdflajsldfkjasljdf asdfjklasdfkjasldkfj asdf';

var newtext = text.replace(image, '');

alert(newtext);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating an element and setting the string as the inner HTML, then looking for the image and remove it?

For example

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = text;

var img = container.querySelector('img[src="' + image + '"]');
container.removeChild(img);

var newtext = container.innerHTML;
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u1mt0tbz/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to remove tags

```
var newT = text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/, '')

console.log(newT );
```